# What is the value of $[K : \Bbb F_p]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field of order $p^{23}$;$p$ is a prime .Let $\phi: F\to F$ be the field automorphism of $F$ sending $a$ to $a^p$. Let $K := \{a\in F:\phi (a)=a\}$.

> What is the value
>   of $[K : \Bbb F_p]$?

Clearly $\{0,1\}\subset K$.But to find $[K : \Bbb F_p]$ we have to first find $K$.

How should I find $[K : \Bbb F_p]$? Please give hints.

Comment: Let $q=p^n$, then $[\mathbb{F_q}:\mathbb{F}_p]=n$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elements of $K$ are just the roots of $x^p-x=0$. This is a polynomial over a field with degree $p$ and so it has $p$ roots, hence $K=\Bbb F_p$ and the dimension is $1$.

As a fun side-note $[F:\Bbb F_p]=23$ is prime, so it has only two sub-fields, both trivial (i.e. itself and the prime field). So as long as you can see that $\phi$ does not fix **all** of $F$, you know it fixes a proper subfield, hence it must be that $K=\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: Thank you very much;Regarding the second approach how do you know it does not fix all of $F$

Comment: @PeterPan It does not fix anything that is not in $F_p$. There are many ways to see this. First, by observing that $x^p-x=0$ implies $x\in F_p$. Second, by using a primitive root of $F$ and seeing that $\phi$ does not fix the primitive root directly.

Comment: I did not get that ;It is obvious that it does not fix anything outside $F$ because all our discussions are in $F$,we require to show that $K=\Bbb F_p$@i707107

Comment: @PeterPan because if it did then $x^p-x$ would have more than $p$ solutions, which is impossible (it's a fact from ring theory about polynomials over integral domains).

Comment: That's clear to me ;What I am asking is how is your $2nd $ approach different from the first one as that was your idea in 1st line

Comment: @PeterPan the first one requires you show there are exactly $p$, the second requires you show there are at most $p$ and combines it with the prime degree observation to go the rest of the way.

Comment: Okay;Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The set of elements of $\mathbf F_{p^{23}}$ invariant by the Frobenius endomorphism $\operatorname{Fr}\colon x\mapsto x^p$  contains the prime subfield $\mathbf F_p$, and is the set of roots of the polynomial $X^p-X$. As a polynomial of degree $p$ in an integral domain has at most $p$ roots , and $\lvert \mathbf F_p\rvert=p$, it follows the invariant subfield is exactly  $\mathbf F_p$.